# Converting a dynamic query to use bind variables in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a dynamic search query that I would like to convert to make use of bind variables.  The dynamic portion of the of query is in the `where` clause, and using a series of `if` statements to build a string that is concatenated to the rest of the query string.  That query is then used in the `for` clause of a `open`statement, which the result set is the return parameter.  I'm not really sure how to accomplish this.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE run_search(i_unit_id           IN lu_unit.fsu_id%TYPE,
                     i_equipment         IN tbl_component.component%TYPE,
                     i_equipment_status  IN tbl_component.equipment_status%TYPE,
                     i_equipment_type    IN tbl_component.equipment_type%TYPE,
                     i_equipment_subtype IN tbl_component.equipment_sub_type%TYPE,
                     i_system_id         IN tbl_component.system_id%TYPE,
                     i_association_code  IN tbl_component_assc_code.assc_code%TYPE,
                     i_manufacturer      IN lu_component_manu_model.equipment_manufacturer%TYPE,
                     i_manumodel         IN lu_component_manu_model.equipment_model%TYPE,
                     o_results           OUT sys_refcursor)  AS

  v_query VARCHAR2(32767) := '';
  v_where VARCHAR2(32767) := ' 1= 1';

BEGIN

  IF i_unit_id IS NOT NULL THEN 
    v_where := v_where || ' AND unit_id=''' || i_unit_id ||''' ';
  END IF;
  IF i_equipment IS NOT NULL THEN 
    v_where := v_where || ' AND lower(component) LIKE ''%' || lower(i_equipment) ||'%'' ';
  END IF;
  IF i_equipment_status IS NOT NULL THEN 
    v_where := v_where || ' AND equipment_status=''' || i_equipment_status ||''' ';
  END IF;
  IF i_equipment_type IS NOT NULL THEN 
    v_where := v_where || ' AND equipment_type=''' || i_equipment_type ||''' ';
  END IF;
  IF i_equipment_subtype IS NOT NULL THEN 
    v_where := v_where || ' AND equipment_sub_type=''' || i_equipment_subtype ||''' ';
  END IF;
  IF i_system_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    v_where := v_where || ' AND system_id=''' || i_system_id || ''' ';
  END IF;
  IF i_association_code IS NOT NULL THEN
    v_where := v_where || ' AND EXISTS ( select null from tbl_component_assc_code where assc_code = ''' || i_association_code || ''' and component_id = vcs.component_id )';
  END IF;
  IF i_manufacturer IS NOT NULL THEN
    v_where := v_where || ' AND equipment_manufacturer=''' || i_manufacturer || ''' ';
  END IF;
  IF i_manuModel IS NOT NULL THEN
    v_where := v_where || ' AND equipment_model=''' || i_manuModel || ''' ';
  END IF;

  v_query := 
    '     SELECT rownum, results.* '
  ||'     FROM '
  ||'       ( SELECT '
  ||'           count(*) OVER () ' || ' as total_results, '
  ||''
  ||'           site_id, site_display_name, '
  ||'           unit_id, unit_display_name, '
  ||'           system_id, system_display_name, '
  ||'           component_id, component, component_description, equipment_description, '
  ||'           equipment_status, equipment_model, equipment_serial_number, equipment_type, equipment_sub_type, '
  ||'           template_ids '
  ||''
  ||'         FROM vw_component_search '
  ||'         WHERE ' || v_where 
  ||'         ORDER BY unit_display_name, component '
  ||'       ) results '
  ;
  OPEN o_results FOR v_query;
END run_search;
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774122/are-pl-sql-variables-in-cursors-effectively-the-same-as-bind-parameters/29774973#29774973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the query without dynamically creating it so you include all the parameters and just ignore those which are `NULL` (please profile it to test whether there are any performance issues compared to a dynamic query):

```
PROCEDURE run_search(i_unit_id           IN lu_unit.fsu_id%TYPE,
                     i_equipment         IN tbl_component.component%TYPE,
                     i_equipment_status  IN tbl_component.equipment_status%TYPE,
                     i_equipment_type    IN tbl_component.equipment_type%TYPE,
                     i_equipment_subtype IN tbl_component.equipment_sub_type%TYPE,
                     i_system_id         IN tbl_component.system_id%TYPE,
                     i_association_code  IN tbl_component_assc_code.assc_code%TYPE,
                     i_manufacturer      IN lu_component_manu_model.equipment_manufacturer%TYPE,
                     i_manumodel         IN lu_component_manu_model.equipment_model%TYPE,
                     o_results           OUT sys_refcursor) 
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_results FOR
  SELECT rownum,
         results.*
  FROM   ( SELECT count(*) OVER () as total_results,
                  site_id,
                  site_display_name,
                  unit_id,
                  unit_display_name,
                  system_id,
                  system_display_name,
                  component_id,
                  component,
                  component_description,
                  equipment_description,
                  equipment_status,
                  equipment_model,
                  equipment_serial_number,
                  equipment_type,
                  equipment_sub_type,
                  template_ids
           FROM   vw_component_search
           WHERE (   i_unit_id IS NULL
                 OR  unit_id= i_unit_id )
           AND   (   i_equipment IS NULL
                 OR  lower(component) LIKE '%' || lower(i_equipment) || '%' )
           AND   (   i_equipment_status IS NULL
                 OR  equipment_status= i_equipment_status )
           AND   (   i_equipment_type IS NULL
                 OR  equipment_type= i_equipment_type )
           AND   (   i_equipment_subtype IS NULL
                 OR  equipment_sub_type= i_equipment_subtype )
           AND   (   i_system_id IS NULL
                 OR  system_id= i_system_id )
           AND   (   i_association_code IS NULL
                 OR  EXISTS ( select null
                              from   tbl_component_assc_code
                              where  assc_code = i_association_code
                              and component_id = vcs.component_id ) )
           AND   (   i_manufacturer IS NULL
                 OR  equipment_manufacturer= i_manufacturer )
           AND   (   i_manuModel IS NULL
                 OR  equipment_model= i_manuModel )
           ORDER BY unit_display_name, component
         ) results;
END run_search;
```

(I've not compiled the above code - so there may be some errors).

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to avoid such headache at all. 'SP returning resultset' is a usual practise in a poor legacy things such as MSSQL2000, but in unnecessary and doubtful in Oracle.

If you wish to do this, I'd advice you to do something like this:

```
procedure MakeGarbage(value_mask varchar2) return sys_refcursor is
  cur integer;
  stmt varchar2(32000 byte);
  type TParamTable is table of varchar2(1000) index by varchar2(20);
  params TParamTable;
  i varchar2(20);
begin
  stmt := 'select * from table where 1 = 1 ';
  if value_mask is not null then
    stmt := stmt || ' and value like :value_mask ';
    params('value_mask') := value_mask;
  end if;
  ...
  cur := dbms_sql.create_cursor;
  dbms_sql.open_cursor(cur, stmt, dbms_sql.native);
  i := params.first;
  while i is not null loop
    dbms_sql.bind_variable(i, params(i));
    i := params.next(i);
  end loop;
  return dbms_sql.to_ref_cursor(cur);
end;
```

Comment: Finally a guy who properly understands how to create dynamic statements in Oracle. You don't find so many here.

Comment: Could you possibly explain this answer a little better, because I'm having a hard time following.

Comment: Seems like a brilliant answer . I hope the writer of this answer could explain a little bit more so that I (as a beginner ) can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

every reference to a PL/SQL variable is in fact a bind variable.

you can check this asktom link 
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2320123769177

and check "Dynamic SQL" from this link http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html