# Variables in PL/SQL; always bind variables?

Tags: variables, plsql, bind

I read this question: [Are PL/SQL variables in cursors effectively the same as bind parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774122/are-pl-sql-variables-in-cursors-effectively-the-same-as-bind-parameters)

The answers given were very good. Rather than use that thread and ask for clarification (as the rule states), I wish to ask a clarification here.
Should (can) we assume every variable in a PL/SQL statement is a bind variable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, whenever we use a PL/SQL variable in embedded SQL it is a bind variable.

If we don't use it in SQL, then it is just a variable of course, because bind variables are an SQL thing only. As soon as we use it in SQL in our PL/SQL package, function or whatever, it becomes a bind variable for the SQL engine.

```
declare
  v_one    varchar2(100);
  v_two    varchar2(100);
  v_three  varchar2(100);
begin
  v_one := 'one';
  v_two := 'two';

  select col_three into v_three from mytable where col_one = v_one;
end;
```

v_one, v_two and v_three are all PL/SQL variables. However, there is SQL in our PL/SQL block and we are using `v_one` there in the WHERE clause. So `v_one` is a bind variable in that SQL statement. (`v_three` is just the return value from the query. `into v_three` is not SQL, but PL/SQL, as SQL knows no INTO keyword.) `v_two` is not even used in any SQL, so it is never being used as a bind variable.